# Can't resolve this error: Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have been banging my head against the wall for several hours, have dug into the SO posts, but still no luck.  I use the LoaderInfo class in another function and it works fine, but this one doesn't work and will always throw the error listed in the title.  Any and all help greatly appreciated!

I have the following javascript function:

```
function changePage(selectedPg, lowerBound, upperBound) {
    let pageInfo = {
        'nbrPages' : 1, 
        'lowerBound' : 1,  
        'upperBound' : 1,  
        'selectedPage' : 1,  
        'dispCnt' : 15,  
        'filterAppId' : 1,  
        'filterValue' : ["blah", "blah"],
        'filterType' : "in",
        'sortAppId' : 1,
        'sortOrder' : "asc"
    };

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url :  "/allocation/changepage",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType : "json",       
        data : JSON.stringify(pageInfo),
        success : function(response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changepage")
public String dashboardChangePage(@RequestBody LoaderInfo loaderInfo, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    model.addAttribute("loaderInfo", loaderInfo);

    return dashboardList(model, request);
}
```

and here is the LoaderInfo class:

```
public class LoaderInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7888322801282198737L;

private Integer nbrPages; 
private Integer  lowerBound;  
private Integer  upperBound;  
private Integer  selectedPage;  
private Integer  dispCnt;  
private Integer  filterAppId;  
private ArrayList<String> filterValue;
private String filterType;
private Integer sortAppId;
private String sortOrder;

public LoaderInfo(Integer nbrPages, Integer lowerBound, Integer upperBound, Integer selectedPage, Integer dispCnt,
        Integer filterAppId, ArrayList<String> filterValue, String filterType, Integer sortAppId, String sortOrder) {
    super();
    this.nbrPages = nbrPages;
    this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
    this.selectedPage = selectedPage;
    this.dispCnt = dispCnt;
    this.filterAppId = filterAppId;
    this.filterValue = filterValue;
    this.filterType = filterType;
    this.sortAppId = sortAppId;
    this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
}

public LoaderInfo() {
}

...getters and setters...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a matching } for your { in
public class LoaderInfo implements Serializable {

Comment: I added the closing brace for completeness.